# How can i sort the table by "DateAdded" in Material UI Table Component for React Js?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, material-ui

I am using Table Component of Material UI in my React Project. I have multiple columns in that which includes the record added on that date. How can I sort my table based on the date when the record is added? 
I am receiving UNIX Timestamp and converting it in mm/dd/yyyy format for readability.

I am using Materila -ui Table component :
https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/

I tried to pass an array of Dates to sort function but it did not work out as it is expecting the array with all the columns.

The expected behavior is that when I click on sort icon nearby date added column, it should sort the table based on date added either Ascending or Descending.

```
function desc(a, b, orderBy) {
  console.log(a.addedDate)
  if (b.addedDate < a.addedDate) {
    console.log(b.addedDate)
    return -1;
  }
  if (b.addedDate > a.addedDate) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

    function stableSort(array, cmp) {
      const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
      stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
        const order = cmp(a[0], b[0]);
        if (order !== 0) return order;
        return a[1] - b[1];
      });
      return stabilizedThis.map(el => el[0]);
    }

    function getSorting(order, orderBy) {
      return order === 'desc' ? (a, b) => desc(a, b, orderBy) : (a, b) => 
    -desc(a, b, orderBy);
    }

    const rows = [
      { id: 'id', numeric: false, label: 'ID'},
      { id: 'lastname', numeric: true, label: 'lastname' },
      { id: 'firstname', numeric: true, label:'firstname' },
      { id: 'email', numeric: true, label: 'email'},
      { id: 'dateadded', numeric: true, label: 'dateadded' }
     ];


    class EnhancedTableHead extends React.Component {
      createSortHandler = property => event => {
        this.props.onRequestSort(event, property);
      };

      render() {
        const { onSelectAllClick, order, orderBy, numSelected, rowCount } 
    = this.props;

    return (
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell padding="checkbox">
            <Checkbox
              indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
              checked={numSelected === rowCount}
              onChange={onSelectAllClick}
            />
          </TableCell>
          {rows.map(
            row => (
              <TableCell
                key={row.id}
                align={row.numeric ? 'right' : 'left'}
                padding={row.disablePadding ? 'none' : 'default'}
                sortDirection={orderBy === row.id ? order : false}
              >
                <Tooltip
                  title="Sort"
                  placement={row.numeric ? 'bottom-end' : 'bottom-start'}
                  enterDelay={300}
                >
                  <TableSortLabel
                    active={orderBy === row.id}
                    direction={order}
                    onClick={this.createSortHandler(row.id)}
                  >
                    {row.label}
                  </TableSortLabel>
                </Tooltip>
              </TableCell>
            ),
            this,
          )}
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
    );
      }
    }

My Table Body looks like following:

     <TableBody>
                  {stableSort(data, getSorting(order, orderBy).slice(page* rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map(n => {
                  var convertedTimeStamp;
                  var d = new Date(n.addedDate);
                  convertedTimeStamp = d.toLocaleDateString();
                  if (n.nuid.indexOf(this.state.filterText) === -1 ) {
                    return;
      }
                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover

                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={n.id}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
                          {n.id}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">{n.lastName}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">{n.firstName}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="left">{n.email}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{convertedTimeStamp} . 
   </TableCell>

                        </TableRow>
                      );
                    })}

            </TableBody>
```

Comment: Can you share the code for sort function? It is very difficult to help without having any code for reference.

Comment: Have updated my question @User97

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem? I`m having hte same issue now

Comment: Yes. I have updated my desc function, where 'a' is an object of an array representing the whole table data.  Please take a look. @Masha